# Parsing 1994 TeX

Tags: htlatex, make4ht

I have these 1994 TeX documents which I would like to produce html and pdf files from.

Here's an example of one of them: https://github.com/lisp-docs/cl-standard/blob/master/new-spec/spec-source/chap-6.tex

**Edit:** Per @michal.h21 I added the plain text configuration in the file but it still fails.

**Edit:** I made a GitHub repository to be easier to share: https://github.com/lisp-docs/cl-standard/tree/master/new-spec/spec-source

**Edit** There is a modified version of the original files which is supposed to work: https://gitlab.com/vancan1ty/clstandard_build However, I was not able to produce HTML from it.

I tried the `make4ht` and `pdftex` both producing many thousands of errors.

The files themselves were compiling at the original time and there are PDFs around of these documents, however, converting from PDF to HTML causes a loss of tables and other formatting which is very important.

Here are samples of the errors I'm getting

```
htlatex: ?  598  Illegal parameter number in definition of \:temp.
htlatex: ?  598  Argument of \h:alignII has an extra }.
htlatex: ?  598  Paragraph ended before \h:alignII was complete.
```

I would assume there's a way to compile this that should work.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `TeX4ht` purely based on successful compilation of your application file, so it's better to compile the files with the current version of either `MikTeX` or `TeXLive` and then try with `TeX4ht`

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that? I have text installed in my mac but neither miktex or texlive show up. texliveonfly does not like it compiles files

Comment: Oh my bad, it does that, just got confused by the `--help` message saying it downloads things on the fly

Comment: I got about 49,000 lines of errors. Maybe there's a compiler argument that can be passed in with `-a` for the compatibility mode. Do you know where the docs are or what it is? I couldn't find it in these docs https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html

Comment: you haven't shown what errors you got but that is plain tex not latex, plain tex has not changed in any essential way since 1994 so I'd be surprised if you get any errors that you did not get at the time

Comment: This seems like a plain TeX file. [Here are the instructions](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#plain-tex) on how to compile Plain TeX. I've tried to add that code to `includer.tex`, but got bunch of errors. The main problem is that it uses PDF primitives, which cause immediate fatal error in the DVI mode, but other than that, it will also need redefinition of a lot of commands to produce some sensible HTML output and to suppress various errors.

Comment: an error count in tex is always meaningless, you get 1 error and could stop there, if you choose to scroll past the error tex may recover but typically can not and will generate arbitrary sputrious messages as it attempts to recover.

Comment: The file linked by you seems to be plain TeX, but not to be the main .tex-file of the document in question: E.g., control sequences `\Head`, `\HeadI`, `\secref`, `\VersionDisclaimer`,  `\beginSimpleChapter` and `\beginSimpleChapter` by default are not defined when starting running TeX or pdfTeX or pdfeTeX. So there must be some superordinate .tex-file with directives either for defining these control sequences (and probably some more stuff) or for inputting other .tex-input-files wherein these control sequences are defined.

Comment: This is the actual source I'm using: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/lisp/doc/standard/ansi/dpans/ I can use the other code as well, it just doesn't show the changes he made to the originals

Comment: latexml can handle plain tex to html.  I'm not sure how well it would handle this.  I'm having trouble spotting the entry point / main file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a plain (pdftex) file, with a supplied build script `maker.sh`  but simply running

```
pdftex includer
```

Runs without error producing:

```
Output written on includer.pdf (1356 pages, 3233284 bytes).
```

Comment: I see that the file cannot be from 1994 ...

Comment: @JosephWright 2017 according to git: https://gitlab.com/vancan1ty/clstandard_build/-/commits/master/includer.tex?ref_type=heads

Comment: @JosephWright although `\def\timestamp{{Fri 12-Aug-1994 6:35pm EDT}}`

Comment: Sure, but it uses .e.g `navigator`

Comment: When doing `make4ht includer "mathml"` however it fails with `htlatex: ? 26  TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].`

Comment: This is really the files I'm working with http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/Web/Groups/AI/lang/lisp/doc/standard/ansi/dpans/ dpans3.tgz and dpans3r.tgz is the last update of the draft

Comment: @Daniel well of course, as make4ht/tex4ht assumes latex, you can force it to use plain as Michal commented under your question, but you would need to configure a lot of the custom mactros to produce custom html, or perhaps simpler just take the pdf and export it from acrobat or similar to html or word and get html that way

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks so much for your answers. I am now trying to do as you and @michal.h21 said. I just did it with one file https://github.com/lisp-docs/cl-standard/blob/master/new-spec/spec-source/chap-6.tex and got errors that I don't understand `htlatex: ? 598  Illegal parameter number in definition of \:temp.`

Comment: if I try that (using the files in original git) with pdftex I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\xbeginchapter ...\setbox \comline \null \outline `   as the navigator pdf outline not set up, you need it to work in pdftex first

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks. Using the https://gitlab.com/vancan1ty/clstandard_build which `pdftex` works for, and replacing it with `make4ht -f html5+detect_engine includer.tex` even after adding the [plain text configuration](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#plain-tex) to each `.tex` file didn't work for me. Any ideas? Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: as i say I'd consider just making the pdf and then converting that to html, the new question is not really related to the main question here, you are not asking for making an old document work as before; you are asking to write a new plain-tex to html generator that has not existed so far. It's possible of course but...   (the plain tex hack sugested is just a quick hack to make simple plain tex documents look enough like latex that a latex to html convert works, it's not really expected to work here without a lot of effort)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I would like to modify the `.tex` files to turn them into the new version of LaTeX so that I can do a regular non plain text conversion to html using make4ht, is there a guide to do that? What would you recommend?

Comment: you may find a different converter such as lwarp or latexml might do better, but otherwise there is no automated tool you just need to edit the doc and rewrite the markup, this is not a matter of new v old, plain tex and latex have always been available as alternative formats, there is no general rule especially as plain tex has no pre-defined markup for different fonts or cross referencing or numbering etc, so a plain tex document uses custom locally defined macros, so you need to work out what those macros are doing and write equivalent latex markup, there can be no general tool @Daniel